# FOSUserBundle: resetting password page finds user that does not exist

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I am using FOSUserBundle with Symfony 3.4

I am trying to reset the user password and this works fine; only problem is that I can put ANY email and the status would be true saying that the email has been sent ??

How is it possible that FOS is finding a user that does not exist ? or did I miss something in my template ?

As far as I understand the status block is what should be displaying the error but it is always a success.

I have not overridden any of the default controller

```
{% extends 'UserBundle:Resetting:request.html.twig' %}

{% trans_default_domain 'FOSUserBundle' %}

{% block status %}
  {{ 'resetting.check_email'|trans({'%tokenLifetime%': tokenLifetime})|nl2br }}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no problem and in addition it is a good behavior. Because otherwise, a person could easily devour a lot of users, which will cause a security problem. So if the user does not exist, not the pain to mention. 
Again, if you look closely at this class (in fosuserbundle repository) via the link :
[ResettingController](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Controller/ResettingController.php), more precisely the method **sendEmailAction**, at the level of the 2nd control structure if

```
if (null !== $user && !$user->isPasswordRequestNonExpired($this->retryTtl))
```

you can notice that if the user does not exist then no mail is sent, the instructions inside the if are not executed and we go directly to a redirection instruction.

```
return new RedirectResponse($this->generateUrl('fos_user_resetting_check_email', array('username' => $username)));
```

That's why you see success all the time. Also this redirection above can be executed even in the case the user exists. That's how I tried to have an attempt to understand this process.